# SQLalchemy: joining one table on two columns

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I have to join two tables, where the first table contains two reverences to the second. E.g. The first table owns the columns START_ID and END_ID. The second table contains the positions. How can I join them in a way that I have access to START and END values. 
Here is what I have tried:

```
    endp = aliased(POSITIONS)
    startp = aliased(POSITIONS)
    trans_data = self.atomic_db.session.query(ONE, endp, startp
                                              ).join(
        endp,
        ONE.start_id == startp.id).join(source_level,
        ONE.end_id == endp.id).values(
        ONE.id, endp.value ,
        startp.value)
```

T

Comment: What is the question? How did it fail? What happened and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

your joins are not ordered right, you should write:

```
endp = aliased(POSITIONS)
startp = aliased(POSITIONS)
trans_data = self.atomic_db.session.query(ONE, endp, startp)\
    .join(endp, ONE.end_id == endp.id)\
    .join(startp, ONE.start_id == startp.id)\
    .values(ONE.id, endp.value ,startp.value)
```

Also, did you want to update or just get query results? if the latter - you do not need ".values"